# Unmet dependencies after installing CUDA 10.2

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, cuda

I tried installing cuda 10.2 using apt. Halfway the installation there was an error. I was able to directly install running the .run file from the Nvidea website. However now when doing:

`$ sudo apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not installed
 cuda-samples-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then when doing:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm7 libllvm7:i386 libnvidia-common-390 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcublas-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libcublas-dev
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 33 not to upgrade.
62 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/42.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 114 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01  libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1 [42.3 MB]
(Reading database ... 473743 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcublas-dev (10.2.2.89-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/nvblas.h', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev 9.1.85-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When doing:

```
$nvcc --version
```

I get:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

Any ideas on how to fix the broken packages?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to find a solution online:

1) I switched prime profiles to intel.
2) moved cuda.list file somewhere else (the 10.2 version that I had installed)
3) Commented lines in .bashrc where it pointed path to cuda 10.2 (not sure if necessary)
4) rebooted
5) $ sudo apt --fix-broken install

(and that worked this time!)

6) switched prime profile back to nvidia
7) uncommented lines in .bashrc (reverse step 3)
8) $ source .bashrc

And it worked. I have now cuda 10.2 installed and apt no longer has broken dependencies. :-)

Comment: Hello @Flilpe . Could you give the full path cuda.list.

Comment: Could you please post the commands you used to execute these steps?